# How to send message to every server's text channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot that will scrape covid information and send the information to a specific discord server's text channel. But how can I make the bot to send the data to all server's text channel which it connected ?

Currently I'm specifying which text channel:

```
    channel = client.get_channel(694814300220686399)  # replace with channel id of text channel in discord
    client.loop.create_task(channel.send("abc")
```

Instead of only sending to a specific server's text channel, I want to send it to every channel it has access to.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you'll need a channel with a common name in all the servers... Let's say the name of the channel is 'general'. Then, you can do it this way...

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

for server in client.guilds:
    requiredChannel = discord.utils.get(server.channels, name = 'general')
    await requiredChannel.send("Your message")
```

Comment: It showed me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` . My code : `for server in client.guilds:
        requiredChannel = discord.utils.get(server.channels, name='general')
        client.loop.create_task(requiredChannel.send("test"))`

Comment: Yes.. you6have to add a try/except block or an else case as well. It returns 'None'if there aren't any channels with the specific name found in your server. Add this after the 'requiredChannel' variable: 'if requiredChannel != None:' and then type the line where you send the message under the 'if' block. After that, add an 'else' block and type continue under it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event()
async def on_ready():
    @client.command()
    async def send_info(ctx , heading, content):
        for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
        if channel == "Covid Alert":
            channel.send("**"+Heading+"**\n"+content)
```

sorry for a messy code it could have been done better i think

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this should fit your needs.

```
for channel in guild.text_channels:
    if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
        await channel.send("Message")
```

### Example "covid" commmand

```
@client.command()
async def covid(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    for channel in guild.text_channels: #loops through all channels
        if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages: #checks for permissions
            await channel.send("Message") #sends your message
```

Comment: Cannot find reference 'text_channels' in 'guild.py'

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code, but you have to get a guild object as I did it in the "covid command" (`guild = ctx.guild`). For example by `client.get_guild(id)` (only one server) or if you want, you can send a message to all the servers your bot is in with `for guild in client.guilds:` (add it before `for channel in guild.text_channels:`).